# SQL compare character

Tags: mysql, sql, text

I have this field

```
 {
    "image_intro":"",
    "float_intro":"",
    "image_intro_alt":"",
    "image_intro_caption":"",
    "image_fulltext":"",
    "float_fulltext":"",
    "image_fulltext_alt":"",
    "image_fulltext_caption":""
}
```

and I would to know when image_intro is not empty?

Comment: What did you try so far? If nothing, then please check the [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) first.

Comment: SELECT id, images,
  CASE 
    WHEN images like 'image_intro":""' 
 THEN images
    ELSE "toto"
   END
FROM field


SELECT * FROM `field` WHERE images like 'image_intro'

Comment: *I have this field* Do you mean that shown value is a JSON object which is stored in one column of one row?

Comment: i don 't see it is a JSON object